# Regular conditional probability as a limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

The "Alternate definition" section of [the current version of the Wikipedia article on Regular conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Regular_conditional_probability&oldid=687233479) describes an approach to conditional probability as a limiting process, in a vein similar to the intuitive description often encountered in introductory courses in probability, namely
$$
P(A|X=x) = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{P(A\cap\{X\in(x-h,x+h)\})}{P(X\in(x-h,x+h))}.
$$

Unfortunately, the article does not cite a reference for this alternate definition. The sole reference attached to the article is [1], however, to my best judgment, the alternate definition does not feature there.

I would appreciate a reference to a source, such as a published article, a textbook, or class notes, where this alternate definition is presented and studied. It might be that [1] actually does discusses the alternate definition but that I have missed or didn't realize it, in which case I'd appreciate to be stood corrected: where in the article is it brought up?

---

***References***

[1] D. Leao Jr., M. Fragoso, P. Ruffino, *Regular Conditional Probability, Disintegration of Probability and Radon Spaces*, Proyecciones, Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 23, No 1, pp. 15-29, May 2004. ([pdf](http://www.scielo.cl/pdf/proy/v23n1/art02.pdf))

Comment: The attached paper was too dense for me. However, it looks like this definition is a form of Radon-Nikodym Derivative, or depends on it being applicable.

Comment: Looking at the Wiki Chat behind this issue is also informative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Regular_conditional_probability#.27.27.27this_way_leads_to_irregular_conditional_probability.27.27.27